# can't sync project after adding constraintLayout

Tags: gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

after adding

```
implementation'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
```

android studio can't sync and I get this error:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: core

bellow is all of my dependences:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

I should mention that if I downgrade constrainLayout to beta1, it works well!

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is some bug with constrainLayout alpha and core 1.2.0,
so I changed core from :

```
'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
```

to

```
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0-alpha01'
```

and it solved the problem.